# Express/Passport not setting cookie for supertest agent

Tags: node.js, express, testing, cookies, supertest

I’m trying to do some integration testing for my Express server with supertest and mocha. Users authenticate via Passport LocalStrategy and I’m setting a session cookie with cookie-session. All works fine in the browser and Postman. However I cannot make it work in combination with supertest: Express response does not contain the cookie on the signup/login routes, thus I cannot make any authenticated requests.

On the Express server `cors` middleware is in place and cookies are `sameSite` and `httpOnly`. Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I was running into a very similar issue. After some trial and error I found the "Secure" cookie flag was the issue.
I was using the following configs for 'express-session'

```
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    secret: envVars.SESSION_SECRET,
    name: 'app-name',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { 
      path: '/', 
      secure : true, 
      maxAge : null, 
      sameSite: 'none' 
    } 
}));
```

Removing the secure flag from the cookies fixed the issue.

```
const session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    secret: envVars.SESSION_SECRET,
    name: 'app-name',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { 
      path: '/', 
      // secure : true, 
      maxAge : null, 
      sameSite: 'none' 
    } 
}));
```